# Windows 8 UI and Service References

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I have a simple program that connects to an API, that lists some files I have on a remote location. I created this program for Win7, and it works just fine. I copied the code over to Visual Studio 2012, onto a Metro/Windows 8 UI app and I am getting:

'Api.Client' does not contain a definition for 'GetId' and no extension method 'GetId' accepting a first argument of type 'Api.Client' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The Code:

```
public static Api.Client ClientApi = new Api.Client();

private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
lvFileList.Items.Clear();

var return = ClientApi.GetId();
string strClientName = return.Member.Name.toString();
string strId = return.Member.Id.toString();
//etc
}
```

This is the same exact code that works fine on Visual Studio 2010. Am I missing something? Or is there something wrong on the API side?

Comment: Try to add the service reference again, instead of copying code over. I don't think a Modern UI app can ever make sync call to web services. They should all be async.

Comment: Yup, that's where the problem was. Was not using async.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Store Apps (formerly Metro) uses a scaled back version of the .Net API.  I would suspect that your Api.Client Dll cannot be added to your Windows Store App because it doesn't fit the new framework.  It will likely work with a standard Windows App in VS2012.

See [.NET for Windows Store apps - supported APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx)